# how to add a drop down list

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Report needs option to select multiple super product types

Selection of multiple super product types?

```
IF @superProductType = 'ALL'
    INSERT INTO #ProductDetails
    SELECT pt_sp_type_c, pt_sb_type_c
    FROM product..p_type_p_type
    WHERE pt_sp_type_c NOT IN ('EQUITY','OPTEQTY')
    AND p_type_use_sp_c= 'RPCDB'
    AND p_type_use_sb_c = 'TRD'
    AND pt_rel_stat_c = 'ACTIVE'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO #ProductDetails
    SELECT pt_sp_type_c, pt_sb_type_c
    FROM product..p_type_p_type
    WHERE pt_sp_type_c NOT IN ('EQUITY','OPTEQTY')
    AND pt_sp_type_c IN (@superProductType)
    AND p_type_use_sp_c= 'RPCDB'
    AND p_type_use_sb_c = 'TRD'
    AND pt_rel_stat_c = 'ACTIVE'
```

I have a parameter here @super product type,can anyone help me how to change this code 
Here in this code i need to make some changes: ---parameter is @superProductType 
The above code was for the option to select multiple super product types

when i select All and one value from the drop down list like 'ALL','ASKF'
both the above conditions in the code if else will fail
It should not get selected ALL and other ASKF at the same time 
either should has to select
How can we differentiate that ALL not selecting ALL from together 
if we select ALL remaining values in the drop down list must be deleted
It should not have two values selected together IF ALL only ALL has to select remaining should discard

I am not sure how to eliminate the rest of values in the drop down list

looking for suitable solution,can anybody see the code abnove and tell me what is the change i have to do in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the SSRS parameter to Multivalue then you should change the query to use IN (@ParamName) syntax. so your query would become:

```
IF @superProductType = 'ALL'
    INSERT INTO #ProductDetails
    SELECT pt_sp_type_c, pt_sb_type_c
    FROM product..p_type_p_type
    WHERE pt_sp_type_c NOT IN ('EQUITY','OPTEQTY')
    AND p_type_use_sp_c= 'RPCDB'
    AND p_type_use_sb_c = 'TRD'
    AND pt_rel_stat_c = 'ACTIVE'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO #ProductDetails
    SELECT pt_sp_type_c, pt_sb_type_c
    FROM product..p_type_p_type
    WHERE pt_sp_type_c NOT IN ('EQUITY','OPTEQTY')
    AND pt_sp_type_c IN ( @superProductType )
    AND p_type_use_sp_c= 'RPCDB'
    AND p_type_use_sb_c = 'TRD'
    AND pt_rel_stat_c = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: where you are asking em to add parameter to multi value in the report layout

Comment: Your original question asked how to change the code to use a parameter with multiple values. If you want to get these from the user, then yes, use a Multivalue parameter in the report definition.

Comment: Already there is a parameter added in the procedure as  @superProductType  VARCHAR(8), and next the above code which i have sent earlier.

Comment: by using else if in the same code by passing string values in seperated commas insert into #ProductDetails  SELECT pt_sp_type_c, pt_sb_type_c     FROM product..p_type_p_type WHERE pt_sp_type_c  IN ('A,B,C,D,E,F')   AND pt_sp_type_c = ( @superProductType )     AND p_type_use_sp_c= 'RPCDB'     AND p_type_use_sb_c = 'TRD'     AND pt_rel_stat_c = 'ACTIVE'

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you using Business Intelligence Development Studio to build a SQL Server Reporting Services report? Do you have a multivalue parameter defined in your report (not the query, but in the report?) If so, what is the name of this parameter?

Comment: superProductType is the name of the parameter,yes we are using BIDS,but in the report layout(report parameters)and datatype is string,in the report parameters there are five unchecked boxes one is hidden,internal,multi value,allow null value,allow blank value,we need to check the multi value box here

Comment: If you check the "multi value" check box then you can use this parameter in your queries with in ( @superProductType )